# What is the fastest way to null out certain fields in a delimited string?

Tags: java, algorithm, csv

Currently I am doing it this way (in java, rebuilding the string field by field, nulling out the field when appropriate):

```
String sourceString = (some string)
String[] tokens = sourceString.split(",");
StringBuilder targetString = new StringBuilder();
    boolean[] nullVals = {false, true, false, true, true, true, false}; // want to null out the values at positions 1, 3, 4, and 5
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (nullVals[i]) {
            targetString.append(tokens[i]+",");
        } else {
            targetString.append(",");
        }
    }
```

Is there a faster way?  Would some kind of regex or masking technique be faster?

Comment: Btw use 2 appends for this also `tokens[i] + ","`

Comment: Start by using a profiler and verifying that this piece of code is actually a bottleneck, and therefore worth the time and effort to optimize.

Comment: This is as simple and fast as you're going to get.  If you want to reduce the lines of code replace the `if` with a ternary expression.

Comment: Not performance-related, but your code is going to add an extra comma to the original string.

Comment: Changing to a ternary will add an unnecessary append operation of an empty string

Comment: Questions on various potential optimizations are better suited for [the Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

How is nullVals obtained in the real case? One simple small optimization you can make: Avoid creating another string instance in `tokens + ","`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if (nullVals[i]) {
        targetString.append(tokens[i]);
    }
    targetString.append(',');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  nullVals is constant, so we don't have to get it, just need to null out the same field positions for every delimited string.

Comment: In this case, you might want to pull it out to a constant, so the array doesn't get created dynamically every time the function is invoked

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using streams (including the extra comma you added):

```
    String target = IntStream.range(0,tokens.length)
                             .mapToObj(i -> nullVals[i] ? tokens[i] : "")
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "", ","));
```

If the extra comma was an error, then use

```
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

This creates a stream of indices, extracts the matching tokens or the empty string depending on `nullVals`, then joins the tokens back into a string.

Comment: Thanks, but we have to be Java 7 compatible.

Comment: Then simplify the if-then-else to a ternary expression to save a few lines, if that is your objective.

Comment: I think the objective is execution speed rather than small source code size.